# Gradle sync failed version does not support the ModelBuilder API while version is 3.3

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm fairly new to android development, all of a sudden I'm receiving the following 
error:`The version of Gradle you are using (Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip') does not support the ModelBuilder API. Support for this is available in Gradle 1.2 and all later versions`

Which is strange because my current version is 3.3 and higher then gradle 1.2

I have tried reinstalling android studio and pointing to my local gradle distribution through File --> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Use Local Gradle Distribution: C:\Users\username\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\RandomCharacters\gradle-3.3

While trying to point to the local distribution I get a message which says the following: `Gradle location is incorrect`

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same problem you have.But I ignored that ,then load the project manual reopen the project from local...After that,press VCS->Enable Version Control...then connect